# laravel retrieving data from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I retrieve data that belongs to the user?

Note model :

```
class Note extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'notes';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'data', 'zadanie', 'uwagi',
    ];

    public function pilot() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Pilot::class);
    }
}
```

Pilot model :

```
class Pilot extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'pilots';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'phone', 'email',
    ];

    public function note() {
      return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function show($id)

{

    $notes = Note::with('pilot')->get();


    return view('dziennikpracy.show',compact('notes'));

}
```

At the time being it shows all the notes, and I want it to display only the notes belonging to each user and i don't know how to.

Comment: Add where class

Comment: maybe something like that `$pilotNotes = Pilot::find($id)->note();` where `$id` is the id of user (Pilot) whose notes you want to get

Answer (score 1):

Add whereHas

`Note::whereHas('pilot', function($q) use ($userId) { $q->where('user_id', $userId) })`

Answer (score 1):

It's far easier to do:

```
$notes = Pilot::find($id)->notes()->get();
```

`$id` is the pilot id which may or may not be the function parameter.

Another way is:

```
$pilotWithNotes = Pilot::with("notes")->find($id);
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notes.pilot_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `notes` where `notes`.`pilot_id` = 5 and `notes`.`pilot_id` is not null)

Comment: My tables looks like, Pilot table: id, phone, email. Note table: id , date, remark

Comment: @tomczas There's no foreign key in the note table?

Comment: How would you know which pilot the note belongs to otherwise?

Comment: @tomczas check https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema in particular https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#foreign-keys

Comment: look at my new comment please

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display only notes which belongs to each user

To get notes of one pilot, do this:

```
$notes = Note::where('pilot_id', $pilotId)->get();
```

To get notes for all pilots, do this:

```
$pilots = Pilot::with('notes')->get();
```

And to display all pilots and their notes use nested `foreach` in the view:

```
@foreach ($pilots as $pilot)
    {{ $pilot->name }}
    @foreach ($pilot->notes as $note)
        {{ $note->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: but in my note table i dont have pilot_id should i add it?

Comment: @tomczas yes, you should add it and add `belongsTo()` relationship.

Comment: @tomczas also note, that if you already know pilot's ID and you want to get just one pilot's notes, my code will create just one query to DB, while other guys' solutions will create two.

Answer (score 0):

your query may return collection of data so you can you "groupBy()" method of collection.